# Looping element in sidebar

Tags: bug, advertising

I just noticed this when browsing around, one of the adverts for SO services seems to be incorrectly applied as it's looping itself horizontally. I'm on a Mac using Chrome

[image]

Comment: If you need me to circle the element in question (in case the arrow isn't enough) then just hit me a comment. freehand of course.

Comment: [Should already be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309532/the-newsletter-info-box-is-broken-apparently-network-wide), but let them know if it isn't yet.

Comment: I can't get the popups to actually show up now so i'll try and spot it again and come back lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed and was already addressed on metaSE as a bug.